# My functions from another file are not working in my main file

Tags: function, date, swiftui, import

I have created a bunch of functions in a file called Calendar Helper:

```
import Foundation

class CalendarHelper() {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    
    func monthYearString(_date: Date) -> String {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "LLL YYYY"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    func plusMonth(_date: Date) -> Date {
        
        return calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: date)!
    }
    func minusMonth(_date: Date) -> Date {
        
        return calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: date)!
    }
}
```

I am now trying to use all of these functions in another file called Scroller:

```
  Text(CalendarHelper().monthYearString(dateHolder.date))
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
                .animation(.none)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
```

The error that it is telling me: Value of type 'Calendar Helper' has no member 'monthYearString'

It is also telling me in my Calendar Helper file: Expected '{' in class

I have checked the brackets in Calendar Helper and none seem to be missing and I do not know why my functions are not working in my other file. Any help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `class CalendarHelper {...}` and put a space after the `_` in the functions parameter,
for example `func monthYearString(_ date: Date){...}`

See also:
[classes](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/classesandstructures/#Definition-Syntax)

and

[Omitting Argument Labels](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/functions/#Omitting-Argument-Labels)

Test Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(CalendarHelper().monthYearString(Date()))
            .font(.title)
            .bold()
            .animation(.none)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}

class CalendarHelper {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    
    func monthYearString(_ date: Date) -> String {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "LLL YYYY"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    
    func plusMonth(_ date: Date) -> Date {
        return calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: date)!
    }
    
    func minusMonth(_ date: Date) -> Date {
        return calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: date)!
    }
}
```